# How to get two select query and condition checking from two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have two tables one is transfer and other one is hardwareSKU ....

**Transfer** is having below columns

```
certid,
part_id
part_desc
snum
.....
```

and **hardwareSKU** is having below columns

```
part_id,
productname
numusers..
```

I need to pass snum as input to single storedprocedure and i need to return two select queries

first i need to find whether **snum** exists in Transfer table if it exists i need to get part_id from **Transfer** table and pass this part_id info to **hardwareSKU** to get the all details..

Here i need to return both select statement queries (one is from **Transfer** table for corresponding **snum** and other one is from **hardwareSKU** for corresponding **part_id**)

how can i get two queries with part_id check from second table ..

I am using sql server ..

Would any one please help on this query that would be very grateful to me.

Comment: Can you specify better what you need (help for making the check, help for the queries, etc.)? Can you post what have you tried to do till now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_Name @Psnum INT
AS
BEGIN

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Transfer WHERE snum=@Psnum)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Transfer WHERE snum = @Psnum

SELECT * FROM hardwareSKU WHERE part_id in (SELECT part_id FROM Transfer WHERE snum = @Psnum)

END
END
```